# how to use two AntiForgeryToken in a single page without using The deprecated 'Salt' property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

How to use many `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in one page?

When I put it doesn't work on the remote host, only locally!

I tried to use different strings foreach forgery token
`@Html.AntiForgeryToken("logoff_forgery")` but when I add `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Salt = "logoff_forgery")]` in the controller, I get this following error

```
  'System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.Salt' 
   'The 'Salt' property is deprecated. 
   To specify custom data to be embedded within the token, 
   use the static AntiForgeryConfig.AdditionalDataProvider property.'   
   D:\projects\codesan\app\CodeSan\CodeSan\Controllers\AccountController.cs 
   289  35  CodeSan
```

Does anyone know how to use the static `AntiForgeryConfig.AdditionalDataProvider` ? If yes please share it with me.

Comment: You can include as many `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in a view as you like. What is the problem?

Comment: Doing that it won't work on remote host...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it states in the description `Salt` property is deprecated.

Here is a simple implementation for `IAntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider`

```
public class MyAntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider : IAntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider
{
    public string GetAdditionalData(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        return GenerateTokenAndSaveItToTheDB();
    }

    public bool ValidateAdditionalData(HttpContextBase context, string additionalData)
    {
        Guid token = Guid.TryParse(additionalData, out token) ? token : Guid.Empty;
        if (token == Guid.Empty) return false;

        return GetIfTokenIsFoundInTheDBAndNotExpired(token);
    }

    private string GenerateTokenAndSaveItToTheDB()
    {
        var newToken = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        //save it to the db
        return newToken;
    }
}
```

And you simply register it in the Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AntiForgeryConfig.AdditionalDataProvider = new MyAntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider();
}
```

Comment: And how do I use this? `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` or  `Html.MyAntiForgery()` ? and you mean that for each page I'll save the token in the database? how heavy is this solution!

Comment: In your view you use `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` and whenever the output is generated it will call `GetAdditionalData()` to put it in the token. This was just an example. You do not have to use the db, it can be static hardcoded guid value or something from the `Request`. I just gave you an example to get you started.